# Open and visually browse large CSV files

Tags: data-analysis, data, csv, file-format

Which software do you recommend to open and visually browse large (>2.5 GB) CSV files?

Comment: On what OS, at what max price, and what features (except for scrolling through the lines) do you need? [tag:data-analysis] suggests you want more than just browse. Please see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [EmEditor](https://www.emeditor.com/) for years.  Can open practically any size file (up to 248GB realistically) and can split CSV and other delimited text into columns.  With tons of other features.

There's a free version, but if you need it for a company, then I highly recommend getting the lifetime license.

https://www.emeditor.com/